# Add border for dots in UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I want to add border color for dots in UIPageControl. Here is the small picture of it:

[image]

I am able to put second dot by configuring it from XCode but I cannot make the first and third circles' inside empty. Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not possible with the current properties available for `UIPageControl`. But you can do by integrating any [third party](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=pagecontrol) page control which mimic the functionality of iOS `UIPageControl`.

<sub>Other answer has applied a patch. I highly disagreed with that solution.</sub>

Comment: "Other answer has applied a patch." what other solution

Answer (score 27):

**Edited- Swift 3 & 4 extension** to achieve the same result-

```
extension UIPageControl {

    func customPageControl(dotFillColor:UIColor, dotBorderColor:UIColor, dotBorderWidth:CGFloat) {
        for (pageIndex, dotView) in self.subviews.enumerated() {
            if self.currentPage == pageIndex {
                dotView.backgroundColor = dotFillColor
                dotView.layer.cornerRadius = dotView.frame.size.height / 2
            }else{
                dotView.backgroundColor = .clear
                dotView.layer.cornerRadius = dotView.frame.size.height / 2
                dotView.layer.borderColor = dotBorderColor.cgColor
                dotView.layer.borderWidth = dotBorderWidth
            }
        }
    }

}
```

to use it write below code in viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear()

```
pageControl.customPageControl(dotFillColor: .orange, dotBorderColor: .green, dotBorderWidth: 2)
```

In **Objective-C** use below code-

```
- (void) customPageControlWithFillColor:(UIColor*)dotFillColor borderColor:(UIColor*)dotBorderColor borderWidth:(CGFloat)dotBorderWidth {
    for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < _pageControl.numberOfPages; pageIndex++) {
        UIView* dotView = [_pageControl.subviews objectAtIndex:pageIndex];
        if (_pageControl.currentPage == pageIndex) {
            dotView.backgroundColor = dotFillColor;
            dotView.layer.cornerRadius = dotView.frame.size.height / 2;
        } else {
            dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            dotView.layer.cornerRadius = dotView.frame.size.height / 2;
            dotView.layer.borderColor = dotBorderColor.CGColor;
            dotView.layer.borderWidth = dotBorderWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Output-

[image]

Comment: Is there other way to achieve this?

Comment: @EmrahAkgül if you are setting the page control in storyboard then try calling the `for` loop after `viewDidAppear`. It worked for me. It wasn't working when I called the loop in `viewDidLoad`. Thanks @RiosK

Comment: The `borderColor` and `borderWidth` settings are enough. No need for the rest. `backgroundColor` for states can be set using `pageIndicatorTintColor` and `currentPageIndicatorTintColor`. Upvoting this because it helped. Make sure to call after view appears, like @TheRohanSanap mentioned above.

Comment: @iPeter it is showing in my case. Refer attachment.

Comment: Iterating on subviews could break anytime if view hierarchy gets changed by an OS update.

Comment: adding border width to pagecontrol not to dots, if background is other than white.

Answer (score 20):

Another approach would be to use a pattern image of the correct size (which currently is 7 points in diameter). Here's what the result looks like:

[image: Pagination dots screenshot]

And here's how it's done:

```
let image = UIImage.outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize(width: 7.0, height: 7.0), color: .darkGray)
self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: image!)
self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .darkGray
```

Which uses this simple little extension to `UIImage`:

```
/// An extension to `UIImage` for creating images with shapes.
extension UIImage {

    /// Creates a circular outline image.
    class func outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize, color: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
                return nil
        }

        context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        // Inset the rect to account for the fact that strokes are
        // centred on the bounds of the shape.
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size).insetBy(dx: lineWidth * 0.5, dy: lineWidth * 0.5)
        context.addEllipse(in: rect)
        context.strokePath()

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

The downside of this is that if the dot size changes in an OS update, the image will look weird as it will be tiled or clipped.

Comment: Some how this not work on iOS version 14.7.1

Answer (score 16):

**SWIFT 3 Version** from @RiosK

```
func updatePageControl() {
    for (index, dot) in pageControl.subviews.enumerated() {
        if index == pageControl.currentPage {
            dot.backgroundColor = dotColor
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2;
        } else {
            dot.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2
            dot.layer.borderColor = dotColor.cgColor
            dot.layer.borderWidth = dotBorderWidth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to put call nice function in the viewDidAppear and didFinishAnimating to get it working.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**. You can assign borderColor and then observe currentPage property to change dots' border:

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {

    var borderColor: UIColor = .clear

    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            updateBorderColor()
        }
    }

    func updateBorderColor() {
        subviews.enumerated().forEach { index, subview in
            if index != currentPage {
                subview.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
                subview.layer.borderWidth = 1
            } else {
                subview.layer.borderWidth = 0
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using [SMPageControl](https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl). It's a really awesome Framework written in Objective-C, so it's capable with Swift 2 and Swift 3.

[image]

The usage is completely simple:

```
pod 'SMPageControl'
```

Then in your `PageViewController`:

```
import SMPageControl

class MyController: UIPageViewController {

     var pageControl = SMPageControl()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stylePageControl()
    }

private func stylePageControl() {

    pageControl = SMPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    pageControl.numberOfPages = yourPageControllerArray.count

//  the first (first) picture is the item in the bar, that is unused
//  the second (currentFirst) is an item that we use, when this is the current active page
//  in this example, we don't have dots, but we use "pictues" as dots

    let first = UIImage(named: "pageHome")?.imageWithColor(UIColor.grayColor())
    let currentFirst = first?.imageWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor())

    pageControl.setImage(first, forPage: 0)
    pageControl.setCurrentImage(currentFirst, forPage: 0)

    let second = UIImage(named: "pageMusic")?.imageWithColor(UIColor.grayColor())
    let currentSecond = second?.imageWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor())

    pageControl.setImage(second, forPage: 1)
    pageControl.setCurrentImage(currentSecond, forPage: 1)

    pageControl.indicatorMargin = 30.0 // this is the space between the dots

    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
}
```

UIImage Extension I've used:

```
extension UIImage {

    func imageWithColor(color1: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        color1.setFill()

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()! as CGContextRef
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)

        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) as CGRect
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage!)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()! as UIImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }

}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Now we could of course use colored dots as the images, (blank colored as unused and color-filled as used) then we would have the asked result.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this two lines and add the desired image !!

```
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor  = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: "slider_selected")!)

pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor =  UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: "slider")!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this custom subclassing of UIPageControl.
iOS 14 allows setting indicator image with SFSymbol.

```
class BorderedPageControl: UIPageControl {

    var selectionColor: UIColor = .black
    
    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            updateBorderColor()
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        currentPageIndicatorTintColor = selectionColor
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    func updateBorderColor() {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let smallConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 8.0, weight: .bold)
            let circleFill = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill", withConfiguration: smallConfiguration)
            let circle = UIImage(systemName: "circle", withConfiguration: smallConfiguration)
            for index in 0..<numberOfPages {
                if index == currentPage {
                    setIndicatorImage(circleFill, forPage: index)
                } else {
                    setIndicatorImage(circle, forPage: index)
                }
            }
            pageIndicatorTintColor = selectionColor
        } else {
            subviews.enumerated().forEach { index, subview in
                if index != currentPage {
                    subview.layer.borderColor = selectionColor.cgColor
                    subview.layer.borderWidth = 1
                } else {
                    subview.layer.borderWidth = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, this is working for my 3 devices: iOS 14.7.1, 12.4.1 and 12.3.1

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** version

```
func customPageControl(dotFillColor: UIColor, dotBorderColor: UIColor, dotBorderWidth: CGFloat) {
    for (pageIndex, dotView) in self.subviews.enumerated() {
        dotView.backgroundColor = currentPage == pageIndex ? dotFillColor : .clear
        dotView.layer.cornerRadius = dotView.frame.size.height / 2
        dotView.layer.borderColor = dotBorderColor.cgColor
        dotView.layer.borderWidth = dotBorderWidth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Luke Rogers answer. I came up with solution for latest iOS versions.

-> Extend UIImage and add these functions:

```
extension UIImage {

/// Creates a circular outline image.
class func outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize, color: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
    }

    context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    // Inset the rect to account for the fact that strokes are
    // centred on the bounds of the shape.
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size).insetBy(dx: lineWidth * 0.5, dy: lineWidth * 0.5)
    context.addEllipse(in: rect)
    context.strokePath()

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

class func ellipse(size: CGSize, color: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
    }

    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    // Inset the rect to account for the fact that strokes are
    // centred on the bounds of the shape.
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size).insetBy(dx: lineWidth * 0.5, dy: lineWidth * 0.5)
    context.addEllipse(in: rect)
    context.fillPath()

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}}
```

Then Extend UIPageControl and add these functions:

```
extension UIPageControl {
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
func outlinedPageIndicaor(color: UIColor, outlinedColor: UIColor? = nil, count: Int) {
    self.pageIndicatorTintColor =
    outlinedColor != nil ? outlinedColor : color
    self.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = color
    let image = UIImage.outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0), color: .red)
    let ellipse = UIImage.ellipse(size: CGSize(width: 9.0, height: 9.0), color: .red)
    self.preferredIndicatorImage = image
    for i in 0..<count {
        self.setCurrentPageIndicatorImage(ellipse, forPage: i)
    }
}

func outlinedPageIndicaor(color: UIColor, outlinedColor: UIColor? = nil, count: Int, index: Int) {
    self.pageIndicatorTintColor =
    outlinedColor != nil ? outlinedColor : color
    self.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = color
    let image = UIImage.outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0), color: .red)
    let ellipse = UIImage.ellipse(size: CGSize(width: 9.0, height: 9.0), color: .red)
    self.preferredIndicatorImage = image
    for i in 0..<count {
        if i != index {
            self.setIndicatorImage(image, forPage: i)
        } else {
            self.setIndicatorImage(ellipse, forPage: index)
        }
    }
}}
```

You can use this if you are using iOS 16 or above in viewDidLoad

```
pageControl.outlinedPageIndicaor(color: .systemMint, count: count)
```

// pass same count as number of pages of pageControl

if iOS version is below 16, then use second method:

in viewDidLoad:

```
pageControl.outlinedPageIndicaor(color: .systemMint, count: count, index: 0)
```

//initial index is passed as 0 for first page

and when current page changes:

```
pageControl.outlinedPageIndicaor(color: .systemMint, count: count, index: index)
```

//pass current page in index

Answer (score -1):

Need to add this in viewDidAppear

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _pageControl.numberOfPages; i++) {
        UIView* dot = [_pageControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == _pageControl.currentPage) {
            dot.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2;
        } else {
            dot.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2;
            dot.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
            dot.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Luke Rogers**'s solution, written in objective-c:

```
-(UIImage *) outlinedEllipse:(CGSize)size color: (UIColor*) lineColor width:(CGFloat) lineWidth {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        if (context == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
        // Inset the rect to account for the fact that strokes are
        // centred on the bounds of the shape.

        CGRect rect = CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 0, 7.0f, 7.0f), lineWidth * 0.5, lineWidth * 0.5);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Modern Luke Rogers (elk_cloner says it's not modern enough for ios14)

```
extension UIImage
{
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842040/add-border-for-dots-in-uipagecontrol
    // modernized Luke Rogers
    class func outlinedEllipse(size: CGSize, color: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let image = renderer.image { context in

            color.setFill()
            
            context.cgContext.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
            // Inset the rect to account for the fact that strokes are
            // centred on the bounds of the shape.
            let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size).insetBy(dx: lineWidth * 0.5, dy: lineWidth * 0.5)
            context.cgContext.strokeEllipse(in: rect)
        }
        return image
    }
    
}
```