# How to set only layer.border-color for UIpage control dots in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

> need to set border color for page control using programmatically or interface builder 
>   Border should not set to complete page control 
>   Just need to apply border color for dots.

I know there is no layer  property for UIcontrol which is super class for page control

I tried to add dynamic views on it.

Still let me know if there is any other possible way

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942636/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-pagination-dots-of-uipagecontrol)?

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842040/add-border-for-dots-in-uipagecontrol)?

Comment: Already checked this will got give the border for that dots

Answer (score 0):

Use as following code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < _pageControl.numberOfPages; i++) {

        UIView* dot = [_pageControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == _pageControl.currentPage) {
            dot.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2;
        } else {
            dot.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2;
            dot.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
            dot.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        }
    }
```

i hope it helps you.